# cannot login in my linux machine

Tags: 12.04, login, users

I am new to Linux. I want to remove the home directory of the user andreas which was the administrator account into a directory called `admins`. I ran the command

```
mv /home/andreas /admins
```

I logged out and tried to log in and it does not let me log in. When I entered the password it leaves me at the login screen. How can I fix it?

```
root@ubuntu:/home# ls -al
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  7 root    root    4096 Mar  4 10:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root    4096 Mar  4 10:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Mar  4 10:10 andreas
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Mar  4 08:58 employees
drwxr-xr-x 19 kostas  kostas  4096 Mar  4 10:23 kostas
drwxrwxrwx  2 nicolas nicolas 4096 Feb 19 08:54 nicolas
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Mar  4 08:56 users



root@ubuntu:/home/andreas# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root    4096 Mar  4 10:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  7 root    root    4096 Mar  4 10:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x 22 andreas andreas 4096 Mar  4 08:55 admins
root@ubuntu:/home/andreas# 


root@ubuntu:/home# ls
admins  andreas  employees  kostas  nicolas  users

root@ubuntu:/home/admins# ls
Desktop    examples.desktop  personal_info.txt  sensitive_info.txt
Documents  mario             Pictures           Templates
Downloads  Music             Public             Videos
root@ubuntu:/home/admins#
```

Comment: Have you moved _andreas_ dir back?

Comment: Pls post the result of `ls -al` do this inside `andreas dir`

Comment: No do `ls -al andreas` and don't remove the one you have posted already

Comment: There is nothing to be alarmed over we just moved _andreas_ back so we aught to see it in there with the others.

Comment: Are we still there????

Comment: I cant move it back. it says no such file or directory

Comment: Pls post the result of `ls -al admins`, Don't move anything again till I tell you

Comment: I have posted what is included in my home directory

Comment: I have posted what's inside /admins

Comment: Now I want to know do you want to get rid of _andreas_ completely as you had wanted? The _andreas_ dir you see is the one we moved back, so its ok where it is...

Comment: No andreas is my administrator and I want to make a folder (admins) to put him inside. Now as I understood here admins directory has all the content that andreas should have

Comment: How can I copy the content of admins to andreas?

Comment: first step: inside `/home/admins` dir do `cp . -R  ../`

Comment: pls hold that last command it should be `cp . -R ../andreas`

Comment: Yes. what is the next step?

Comment: inside admins do `cp . -R ../andreas`

Comment: I did that. Is there anything else that I should do?

Comment: pls check that the files are in andreas, and where is admins. In andreas or in `/home`?

Comment: Yes there all inside andreas

Comment: admins are inside /home/andreas

Comment: ok now `sudo cp -r /etc/skel   /home/andreas`

Comment: Please run this: `sudo cp -r /etc/skel /home/andreas` was attending to my kids

Comment: what does that command do?

Answer (score 2):

You actually moved *andreas* home directory to the location `/admins` so andreas can't log in. To fix we will try to create *another user* and add to the `sudo` group from the `recovery mode` using the `grub menu`.

Steps:

1. Boot into your GRUB menu using the <kbd>shift</kbd> key

   - at boot press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key so you see the grub menu, then
2. Select the `Advance option` from grub menu
3. Select `recovery mode` from the list presented to you.
4. Choose the `root option` from the list seen.
5. Then when the terminal appears press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and type the following in the terminal:

   a. `mount -o remount,rw /`

   b. `adduser new_user_name`

   - enter passowrd and just press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key for all other options

   c. `usermod -a new_user -G sudo`

   d. Type `exit` and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Try to log in.
7. If you login using the new user, return *andreas'* `home` directory using the terminal with:

   ```
   sudo mv /admins /home/andreas
   ```
8. Look at the content of `/home/andreas` it should be the same as before you moved it. Now logout and try to log in as *andreas*.

UPDATE:

9. Since the folder is lacking the required default files for a user:

   a.  Change into the `admins` directory and copy the contents into the `andreas` one level up with: `cp . -R ../`
10. Copy the contents of the `/etc/skel` dir into `andreas` with:

    ```
    sudo cp -r /etc/skel /home/andreas
    ```
11. Make sure these files are present in the `/home/andreas/skel` folder in `andreas`:

    ```
    .bash_logout
    .bashrc
    examples.desktop
    .profile
    ```
12. Change ownership of `skel` folder and its contents:

    ```
    sudo chmod -R andreas:andreas skel
    ```
13. Remove the `admins` folder from `andreas`: `rm -rf admins`
14. Move the `skel` directory and move its content out into the parent folder `andreas`:

    ```
    cp . -r ../
    ```
15. Now the `andreas` folder should have these files in it:

    ```
    .bash_logout  .bashrc   examples.desktop   .profile
    Desktop    examples.desktop  personal_info.txt  sensitive_info.txt
    Documents  mario             Pictures           Templates
    Downloads  Music             Public             Videos
    ```
16. Now we check to see if user `andreas` is ok in two places: `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`:

    ```
    cat /etc/passwd | grep andreas

    # result should like this
    george:x:1000:1000:george,,,:/home/george:/bin/bash

    cat /etc/group | grep george

    # result should be like this:
    adm:x:4:syslog,george
    cdrom:x:24:george
    sudo:x:27:george
    dip:x:30:george
    www-data:x:33:george
    plugdev:x:46:george
    lpadmin:x:108:george
    george:x:1000:    <---------| subject of interest
    sambashare:x:124:george
    docker:x:999:george
    libvirtd:x:134:george
    ```
17. If user `andreas` is not found in either of this places, then use

    ```
    sudo vipw 
    sudo vigr
    ```

    to add them to the `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` file respectively using the format seen there, and set a new password with:

    ```
    sudo passwd andreas
    ```
18. Now to make sure user `andreas` owns the `/home/andreas` run `ls -al /home/andreas` and make sure the `owner = andreas` and `group = andreas`, else run:

    ```
    sudo chown -R andreas:andreas /home/andreas
    ```
19. Now change the password for `andreas` just to be safe:

    ```
    sudo passwd andreas
    ```
20. Now reboot and log in using user `andreas`, if successful you can now *delete* the `new_user` created earlier with: `sudo deluser new_user --delete-home`

Comment: Two alternatives are to move `/admins` back to `/home/andreas` or to set the home directory to `/admins` with `usermod -d /admins andreas`.

Comment: Yes Rex I thought of the move but remembered the OP said a dir _admins_ already existed so felt best bet would be to create _andreas_ and then OP can sort out the dir issue

Comment: While I type adduser andreas it says that user already exist shall I put other name?

Comment: Yes please use another name, after you can fix _andreas_ from the new user

Comment: Once your through let me know so we can look at recovery that directory you moved to `/admins`

Comment: Ok I did it. Now shall I login to new user?

Comment: ok go ahead and do so, and let me know

Comment: I successfully login with the new user

Comment: now use `sudo mv /admins   /home/andreas` to return that dir you moved before

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home# ls
andreas  employees  kostas  nicolas  users
root@ubuntu:/home# cd andreas/
root@ubuntu:/home/andreas# ls
admins
root@ubuntu:/home/andreas# mv /admins /home andreas
mv: target `andreas' is not a directory
root@ubuntu:/home/andreas# mv /admins /home/andreas
mv: cannot stat `/admins': No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:/home/andreas# ls
admins
root@ubuntu:/home/andreas# mv admins /home/andreas
mv: `admins' and `/home/andreas/admins' are the same file
root@ubuntu:/home/andreas#

Comment: I am confused now

Comment: Pleas post it in your original post

Comment: Please do nothing just post the contests of `ls -al /home/andreas`